# Castle Windsor - IoC registration for open generic interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Does Castle Windsor permit registration of an open generic interface or do I need to register each possible typed instance separately?

Example - the below with types T,Z fails upon compilation unless I separately specify T, Z with strong types.

```
 container.Register(Component
      .For<IAdapterFactory<T,Z>>()
      .ImplementedBy<AdapterFactory<T,Z>>()
      .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```

Comment: "Strong types" not an accurate description since templating does use strong types in C#. My point is that Castle Windsor does not seem to accept templates for registration, so it would seem I need to enumerate all possible types within ConstrollerInstaller.cs in order to register the same IAdapterFactory against multiple possible typed invokations. Seems strange.

Comment: it's not Windsor's limitation, it's how .NET runtime works.

Comment: Can you say more about this? "it's not Windsor's limitation, it's how .NET runtime works"

Comment: You cannot close a generic method (like `Component.For<>`) over a non-closed generic type. This is how .NET generics work. Have a look here for some more insight http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It's called *open generic*, and yes, Windsor does support that.

```
 container.Register(Component
             .For(typeof(IAdapterFactory<,>))
             .ImplementedBy(typeof(AdapterFactory<,>))
             .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Comment: One word: wow. Thank you! Just out of curiosity, wonder why Castle folks decided to deviate from more standard C# syntax - <T,Z> instead of <,>?

Comment: This is the only syntax that will work in this scenario and it has noting to do with Windsor. This just is how you obtain an instance of `System.Type` representing an open generic type.

Comment: Probable the fifth time this answer helped me out  - thank you