# Castle Windsor : Auto register for every type from other assembly

Tags: castle-windsor

I am new to Castle Windsor.

In one assembly, Domain.Classes

```
class BaseEntity
{
}

class Entity1 : BaseEntity {}
class Entity2 : BaseEntity {}
class Entity3 : BaseEntity {}
```

In another assembly, I have interface,

```
class GenericImplementation <BaseEntity>: IGenerticInterface<BaseEntity>
{
    // base on BaseEntity
    // does something
}
```

How can I register GenericImplementation for every BaseEntity (Entity1, Entity2, Entity3, etc) given in assembly Domain.Classes?

I tried this way, but not working.

```
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Domain.Classes")
         .BasedOn(typeof(IGenerticInterface<>))
         .Configure(c => c.ImplementedBy(typeof (GenericImplementation<>)))
         .LifestyleTransient());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Castle Windsor - IoC registration for open generic interfaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344708/castle-windsor-ioc-registration-for-open-generic-interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

You can do generic registration as follows:

```
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                 .BasedOn(typeof(IGenerticInterface<>))
                 .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
                 .Configure(c => c.LifestylePerThread()));
```

You can change `.FromThisAssembly()` to look into whatever assembly you need.

You can change `.WithServiceAllInterfaces()` to use a specific implementation but in our systems we register services with all their interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still confused. I tried this, but not working      container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Domain.Classes")
         .BasedOn(typeof(IGenerticInterface<>))
         .Configure(c => c.ImplementedBy(typeof (GenericImplementation<>)))
         .LifestyleTransient());

Comment: If you want to register an implementation manually as you are doing by calling `.ImplementedBy(typeof (GenericImplementation<>)` then you will have to declare the the `<T>` that would be used in the generic declaration inside the `<>` brackets.

Comment: You could try using: `container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Domain.Classes")
                            .BasedOn(typeof(IGenerticInterface<>))
                            .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
                            .LifestyleTransient());`
I have found that using `.WithServiceAllInterfaces()` finds each implementation of `GenericImplementation<CLASS>` and registers it with `IGenericImplementation<CLASS>`

Comment: How can I make sure that classes from assembly ("Domain.Classes") must extends BaseEntity? I don't want to register any dependency classes other than type which extends BaseEnity from Domain.Classes assembly. Thanks

Comment: The registration used above will only register classes that implement the IGenerticInterface<> in the assembly you asked it to look at, as this is what `.BasedOn(typeof(IGenerticInterface<>)` does. Not sure how to limit it further to classes that inherit from BaseEnity as well.