# Dynamically register types in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Let's say I have got an interface and classes: (for asking purpose it will empty)

```
public interface IPerson { }

public class Tom : IPerson {}
public class Philip : IPerson {}
```

And a service interface and its implementation:

```
public interface IHelloService<T> where T : IPerson { }

public class HelloService<T> : IHelloService<T> where T : IPerson { }
```

How can I dynamically register service `HelloService` for every `IProdukt` I have got, I mean I want to register this classes:

```
IHelloService<Tom> -> HelloService<Tom>
IHelloService<Philip> -> HelloService<Philip>
```

Comment: May you remove "where T : IProdukt" from IHelloService<T> interface and HelloService<T> class?

Comment: Not really, but if you have any idea how to make it after removing it please share, maybe I will figure out something :)

Comment: i think this will help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344708/castle-windsor-ioc-registration-for-open-generic-interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's something like this you're after:

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IHelloService<>))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(HelloService<>), new Only<IProduct>())
    .LifestyleTransient());

public class Only<T> : IGenericServiceStrategy
{
    public bool Supports(Type service, ComponentModel component) => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(service.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
}
```

It will close the implementation with the same type argument as the service, but it will restrict possible type arguments to types that implement IProdukt/IPerson (I assume those are meant to be the same?).

See a description of this feature here: http://kozmic.net/2013/07/23/on-castle-windsor-and-open-generic-components/